# cname record for aurora rds update time

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-route53

I am thinking of moving from mysql --> aurora and have a question in regards to cname

1. In route 53 I have a dns CNAME for my database that points to the RDS endpoint; can I just update the cname records after I promote aurora to production to point to the aurora instance. Will there be any delay in my application getting this update? EC2 would be connecting to the database in the same region.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue to use CNAMES, go to your DNS server and make note of the TTL value for this entry. Change the entry to the shortest TTL value.

Wait for the amount of time specified by the old TTL. Upgrade from RDS MySQL to Aurora. Change the DNS entry to point to the new server. Change the TTL back to its previous value.

By following the above steps you will minimize the DNS resolution switch over time.

Comment: I was using cname based on this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-rds-db.html